# Is there a trick to solve binary tree problems with `size` or `height`?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

About `binary trees`, I understand the difference between `size` and `height`: `size` is the number of nodes while `height of a tree` is the max number of edges from the root to the furthest leaf.

However, when dealing with problems involving `height`, my mind is often twisted and can't think straight.

For the following two problems, they are very similar except one with constraints on `size` while the other one with `height`.

---

For example, let's first have the one involving `size`.

> In a completely balanced binary tree, the following property holds for
>   every node: **The number of nodes** in its left subtree and the number of
>   nodes in its right subtree are almost equal, which means their
>   difference is not greater than one.
>
> Write a function to construct **all possible** completely balanced binary
>   trees for a given number of nodes - **n**. The function should generate all
>   solutions via backtracking. Put the letter 'x' as information into all
>   nodes of the tree.

This problem is to generate all possible completely balanced binary tress as long as the property is held.

I think `size` is simple. What I can do is like this:

1. Using recursion
2. If n mod 2 = 1, then generate all such trees with `n=n/2`, then merge every pair of those trees with a new root.
3. If n mod 2 = 0, then generate one set of trees with `n/2` and another set of trees with `n/2-`. then merge every pair (one from a set) with a new root, also don't forget to exchange the elements inside every pair.
4. If n = 0 then return a set with only one Leaf
5. If n = 1 then return a set with only one singleton internal node with two Leaves.

---

When the `size` in the problem is changed to `height`, I don't really know how to cleverly think any more.

> In a height-balanced binary tree, the following property holds for
>   every node: The **height** of its left subtree and the height of its right
>   subtree are almost equal, which means their difference is not greater
>   than one.
>
> Write a function to construct **all possible** height-balanced binary trees
>   for a given number of nodes - **n**. The function should generate all solutions via
>   backtracking. Put the letter 'x' as information into all nodes of the
>   tree.

I think if involving height, things get quite arbitrary.

---

**Is the solution for the 2nd problem is the same as the 1st problem?**

How really should I train myself to handle the height thing? Where is the trick?

Comment: The trick is to understand exponents and logarithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not the same. Consider: (each node's value indicates the height of its subtree)

```
     4
   /   \
  2     3
 /     / \
1     2   2
     / \ / \
    1  1 1  1
```

The left subtree has 2 nodes, the right has 7, yet it is height-balanced.

The first thing you need to do is calculate both the minimum and the maximum number of nodes for some given height (the maximum is simply `2^n-1`, the minimum can be calculated iteratively starting from height 1, or perhaps there's also a formula for that).

Then you need to loop through the heights for the left subtree and the right subtree (which will be the height of the left subtree + 1/0/-1), if we can get to `n` using these heights, that is: the maximum number of nodes for these heights plus one is `>= n` and the minimum number of nodes for these heights plus one is `<= n`, loop through all combinations adding up to `n`, generating all valid trees, and merging them, similarly to what you did for the first problem.

I hope that makes sense.

---

There's no real trick to dealing with problems involving heights - the approach would vary greatly from problem to problem. It's usually important to keep in mind that the height of a balanced tree is `~log2n` and that a complete tree of height `n` has `2^n-1` nodes.

Comment: ` the minimum can be calculated iteratively starting from height 1, or perhaps there's also a formula for that)`, is the recusrive like `min h = 1 + min ((min (h-1) + min (h-2)), (min (h-1) + min (h-1))`?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct, although `min(h-2)` < `min(h-1)`, so it can be simplified to `min(h) = 1 + min(h-1) + min(h-2)`.

Comment: Can I do like this: like you said, for an `n`, we can get `max_h` and `min_h` (`min_h` uses the same way of your `min_nodes`). Then build a list contains all trees with height in the range, each tree is associated with the size. Then we iterate the list, combine any pair whose size sums are `n-1` and whose height diff obey the rule

Comment: That could work, although you may end up doing quite a bit of work to go through all possible pairs of trees to check if their sum adds up to the correct amount and they have the correct height difference (although perhaps I'm misunderstanding your approach). Generating all (sub)trees with the required height and number of nodes should be easy enough (which you could store for future reference), so you could just loop over the valid combinations of heights and generate / lookup the correct trees from there.